# ListAdapter with multiple item types throws ClassCastException

Tags: android, listview, classcastexception, baseadapter

I am building an app for an event and one of the features is a message board. To do this I built a `ListView` and loaded it with messages.

I have two types of message: messages you send, and messages the other send. The layout is slightly different, U use other XML files. I tried my code(below) and it works fine if all the items are of the same type (yours, or the others). But when the types are changing, I get a `ClassCastException`. I know what that means, and where it goes wrong (the itemholders are of different classes, and it tries to make an object of the class its not) but not how to solve it.

Here is my code, this is the getView of my `ChatAdapter`. 
`ChatAdapter` is a class that extends `BaseAdapter`.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    final Message m = messagelist.get(position);
    OwnMessageHolder ownMessageHolder;
    OtherMessageHolder otherMessageHolder;
    if(isSelf(m.getPerson().getId())) {
    if (vi == null) { //convertview==null
        ownMessageHolder = new OwnMessageHolder();
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_chat_own, null);
        vi.setOnClickListener(null);
        vi.setOnLongClickListener(null);
        vi.setLongClickable(false);
        ownMessageHolder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_own_name);
        ownMessageHolder.message = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_own_message);
        vi.setTag(ownMessageHolder);
    }else{//convertview is not null
        ownMessageHolder = (OwnMessageHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    ownMessageHolder.name.setText(m.getPerson().getName());
    ownMessageHolder.message.setText(m.getMessages()[0]);

    vi.setFocusable(false);
    vi.setClickable(true);

    return vi;
    }else {//other
        if (vi == null) { //convertview==null
            otherMessageHolder = new OtherMessageHolder();
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_chat_other, null);
            vi.setOnClickListener(null);
            vi.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            vi.setLongClickable(false);
            otherMessageHolder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_other_name);
            otherMessageHolder.message = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_chat_other_message);
            vi.setTag(otherMessageHolder);
        }else{//convertview is not null
            otherMessageHolder = (OtherMessageHolder)vi.getTag();
        }


        otherMessageHolder.name.setText(m.getPerson().getName());
        otherMessageHolder.message.setText(m.getMessages()[0]);

        vi.setFocusable(false);
        vi.setClickable(true);

        return vi;
    }
}


    public static class OwnMessageHolder {
    public TextView name;
    public TextView message;
}

public static class OtherMessageHolder {
    public TextView name;
    public TextView message;
}
```

and the error log:

```
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hera.lustrumvirgiel.ChatAdapter$OtherMessageHolder cannot be cast to com.hera.lustrumvirgiel.ChatAdapter$OwnMessageHolder
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at com.hera.lustrumvirgiel.ChatAdapter.getView(ChatAdapter.java:57)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2449)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:627)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:440)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:690)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:583)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2106)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12815)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1068)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2452)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4493)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
04-06 23:25:54.720: E/AndroidRuntime(18176):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem? The line the error log is referring to (57) is this one:

> ownMessageHolder = (OwnMessageHolder)vi.getTag();

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use multiple layouts:

```
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_chat_own, null);
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_chat_other, null);
```

But you aren't telling the adapter to expect more than one... This will lead to a lot of problems with ListView's RecycleBin and it won't be as efficient.  Simply override [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and [`getItemViewType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) then use `getItemViewType()` inside `getView()` to load the appropriate layout and the Adapter will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Java's `instanceof` keyword seems to be what you are looking for. It allows you to determine whether an object is an instance of a particular class. This is particularly handy to use in an if statement before casting the object:

```
Object tag = vi.getTag();
if (tag instanceof OtherMessageHolder)
    otherMessageHolder = (OtherMessageHolder)tag;
else // Assume it is an OwnMessageHolder
    ownMessageHolder = (OwnMessageHolder)tag;
```